# measuring a view before rendering it: Flutter

Tags: flutter

I know there is a way to calculate height of a view before rendering/adding to tree in native android and iOS. Is there any equivalent of `view.measure` in Flutter?

Comment: Yes, there are ways, but why?  The design of the layout system keeps you from needing to make such decisions.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz same as the TextPainter. I need to find out whether the constructed page fits the screen without scrolling. If it doesn’t, then break the page into pages so the user could paginate. The page can be huge, so I don’t want to put the page in the tree, calculate, then trim the page as it can bring to a performance issue. If you know a way to measure a widget, please give me an example.